# The view users.views.edit_profile didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

views.edit_profile does not return Fields Error but instead return webpage error.

In views.registration - it does return fields error but in views.edit_profile instead of fields error it return a webpage error. how does it happen when the two have a similar codes?
the below image is the error from views.register after submitted.

views.register field error:

[image]

and this is the error from views.edit_profile. It cause an error because the mobile phone is invalid. The error should be the same from views.register.
views.edit_profile field error:

[image]

**models.py**

CustomUser model: Where I set the validations and made a table.

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(
        _('Username'),
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[UnicodeUsernameValidator()],
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        },
    )
    email = models.EmailField(_('Email Address'), unique=True)
    palotype = models.CharField(_('Type'), max_length=150, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default='Palon-on')
    suffix = models.CharField(_('Suffix'), max_length=150, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('First Name'), validators=[AlphaSpaces()], max_length=150, blank=False)
    middle_name = models.CharField(_('Middle Name'), validators=[AlphaSpaces()], max_length=150, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('Last Name'), validators=[AlphaSpaces()], max_length=150, blank=False)
    birth_date = models.CharField(_('Birth Date'), validators=[BirthdateRegex()], max_length=10, blank=False)
    region = models.CharField(_('Region'), validators=[AlphaSpaces()], max_length=150, blank=False)
    city = models.CharField(_('City'), validators=[AlphaSpaces()], max_length=150, blank=False)
    barangay = models.CharField(_('Barangay'), max_length=150, blank=False)
    unitno = models.CharField(_('Unit / Apartment No.'), max_length=150, blank=True)
    floorno = models.CharField(_('Floor'), max_length=150, blank=True)
    bldgname = models.CharField(_('Building Name'), max_length=150, blank=True)
    housebldgno = models.CharField(_('House/Building No.'), max_length=150, blank=True)
    streetname = models.CharField(_('Street Name'), max_length=150, blank=True)
    villagedistrict = models.CharField(_('Village / District'), max_length=150, blank=True)
    mobileno = models.CharField(_('Mobile Number'), validators=[PhoneRegex()], max_length=150, blank=False)
    landline = models.CharField(_('Landline'), validators=[LandlineRegex()], max_length=150, blank=True)
    qr_code = models.ImageField(upload_to='qr_codes', blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    about = models.TextField(_(
        'about'), max_length=500, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    

    objects = CustomAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'birth_date', 'region', 'city', 'barangay', 'mobileno']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qrcode_img = qrcode.make(self.username)
        canvas = Image.new('RGB', (290, 290), 'white')
        canvas.paste(qrcode_img)
        fname = f'qr_code-{self.username}.png'
        buffer = BytesIO()
        canvas.save(buffer,'PNG')
        self.qr_code.save(fname, File(buffer), save=False)
        canvas.close()

        # if len(str(self.birth_date))<10:
        #     raise ValueError(('Birthdate cannot less than 10 characters.'))
        # elif self.birth_date > datetime.date.today().strftime("%m/%d/%Y"):
        #     raise ValueError(('Birthdate cannot be set as future date.'))
        # elif self.birth_date == datetime.date.today().strftime("%m/%d/%Y"):
        #     raise ValueError(('Birthdate cannot be set equal to todays date.'))

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

User Registration Form:

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'palotype',  'suffix','first_name',
                  'middle_name', 'last_name', 'birth_date','region','city','barangay','unitno','floorno','bldgname',
                  'housebldgno','streetname','villagedistrict','mobileno','landline']
```

**forms.py**

UserEdit Form - I removed the passwords.

```
class UserEditForm(UserChangeForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'palotype', 'suffix','first_name',
                  'middle_name', 'last_name', 'birth_date','region','city','barangay','unitno','floorno','bldgname',
                  'housebldgno','streetname','villagedistrict','mobileno','landline']
```

**views.py**

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            new_user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, new_user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm() 
    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})


def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserEditForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.info(request, 'Information successfully updated!')
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user)
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'change-info.html', args)
```

Note: I tried to use UserRegisterForm as form in edit_profile but I encountered the same error.

I managed to fix the error by this code.

```
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserEditForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            # password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            # user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            # login(request, user)

            messages.info(request, 'Information successfully updated!')
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.info(request, form.errors)
            form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user)
            args = {'form': form}
            return render(request, 'change-info.html', args)
    else:
        form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user)
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'change-info.html', args)
```

fixed result:

[image]

but it's far way different than the views.register.
I would like the error to be the same with views.register.

Comment: add else part of form.is_valid and add httpresponse to it. if form is not valid then what should do? i think when you submit form then it shows this error. so you have to add else part in it. also print(form.errors) to check what is wrong in your submitted form.

Comment: I know that sir, I'm just frustrated coz It's not the same as view_register when they both have almost the same codes. I wanted it to print the error just like the first image I've posted above.